# Extract domains from a Zone file

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have file with this format

```
81535883v2a1.hbrxly.com,a,209.99.40.222
81535883v2a1.hbrxly.com,ns,dns10.parkpage.foundationapi.co
81535883v2a1.hbrxly.com,txt,|v=spf1 a -all
81535883v2a1.nsmodel.com,a,23.245.38.79
81535883v2a1.panbao.net,cname,p.dcoin.co
81535883v2a1.sznissei.com,a,23.224.47.73
81535883v2a1.tauri.com.cn,a,23.244.110.119
81535883v2a1.vemega.net,a,103.232.215.133
```

And I want to extract it into something like this (first line and domain only)

```
hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
nsmodel.com
panbao.net
sznissei.com
tauri.com
vemega.net
```

I have tried using sed,awk,grep but still not working. I don't know, hope someone here can help.

Comment: The best way to approach this would be using regex with the re module. My regex is pretty rusty, but this might work: `url = re.compile(r'.+\.([A-Za-z0-9]+\.[com|ne
t]{3}).+$')` and `url.findall(line)`. Someone can probably come up with a more proper string.

Comment: Do you really want `81535883v2a1.tauri.com.cn` to malform to `tauri.com`?

Comment: @JamesBrown :  `echo 81535883v2a1.tauri.com.cn  |awk -F, '(d=gensub(/^.*\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/,"\\1","g",$1)) && !seen[d]++ {print d}' `
com.cn

Comment: Eh, yes? Does the OP want malformed output, ie `*.tauri.com.cn` to print `tauri.com` as in the question or does he want correct information?

Comment: hmm..not sure. although `tauri.com.cn` make more sense to me. Will let OP to decide.

Comment: Now coding that might require a bit more work than a one-liner.

Comment: @JamesBrown I want a completed domain com.cn ,sorry tht was my typing mistake.anyway thanks for response!problem already solve :)

Answer (score 5):

```
awk -F'[.,]' '{print $2,$3}' OFS="." file

hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
nsmodel.com
panbao.net
sznissei.com
tauri.com
vemega.net
```

Comment: Thanks sir! problem solve now

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -oP '^[^.]+\.\K[^.]+\.[^.,]+' ip.txt 
hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
nsmodel.com
panbao.net
sznissei.com
tauri.com
vemega.net
```

If you need string upto `,`

```
$ grep -oP '^[^.]+\.\K[^,]+' ip.txt 
hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
nsmodel.com
panbao.net
sznissei.com
tauri.com.cn
vemega.net
```

Comment: Thanks sir!working pefectly.. how about make it  automatically sort and remove duplicate domain ?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '{sub(/^[^.]*\./,"",$1)} {print $1}' infile
hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
nsmodel.com
panbao.net
sznissei.com
tauri.com.cn
vemega.net
```

For unique domain names.

```
awk -F, '{sub(/^[^.]*\./,"",$1)} {print $1}' infile |sort -u
```

Or as sp asic suggested

```
awk -F, '{sub(/^[^.]*\./,"",$1)} !seen[$1]++{print $1}'  infile
```

Comment: Thanks brother!work nice also, how about make it  automatically sort and remove duplicate domain ?

Comment: just add `sort -u` in the end of the command.

Comment: @soFan, or modify the awk command itself.. `awk -F, '{sub(/^[^.]*\./,"",$1)} !seen[$1]++{print $1}'`

Comment: @spasic thanks, I was being lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/[^.]*\.\([^,]*\).*/\1/' file
hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
nsmodel.com
panbao.net
sznissei.com
tauri.com.cn
vemega.net
```

Comment: Thanks sir,working like hell!

Answer (score 0):

### **Using Perl:**

```
perl -ne ' use strict; use warnings; $_ =~ m/(.*?)\.(.*?),(.*)/g; {print $2, "\n"}' file
```

**OUTPUT**

```
hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
hbrxly.com
nsmodel.com
panbao.net
sznissei.com
tauri.com.cn
vemega.net
```

Comment: Thanks you!aprreciated the answer.working like charm.

Answer (score 0):

In GNU awk. It only prints the first occurrance of each domain and also works with addresses like `host.subdomain.domain.tldn`.

```
$ awk -F, '(d=gensub(/^.*\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/,"\\1","g",$1)) && !seen[d]++ {print d}' file
hbrxly.com
nsmodel.com
panbao.net
sznissei.com
com.cn
vemega.net
```

If you would like the subdomains (ie. everything but the hostname) as well, then:

```
$ awk -F, '(d=gensub(/^[^.]+\.(.+)$/,"\\1","g",$1)) && !seen[d]++ {print d}' file
hbrxly.com
nsmodel.com
panbao.net
sznissei.com
tauri.com.cn
vemega.net
```

Comment: I just try still not working,its very good idea if i can also grab the subdomain.thanks for the answer anyway.